# (Override || Extend) Javascript Method

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

I want to change the method DomElement.appendChild() to work differently when applied on an Object that I have created:

```
// using MooTools;
var domElement = new Class({...});

var MyObject = new domElement(...);

$(document).appendChild(MyObject); // Error

// I want to add to (extend) appendChild, to do something specific, when:
alert(MyObject instanceof domElement); // true
```

I could do this by modifying the mootools.js, but I want to avoid this at all costs, because I am certain one day, some other developer will overwrite the js file with an updated version, and I will be imprisoned for murder.

Please, keep me out of jail!

Comment: Now, that would really be something: **jailtime for hindering updates of shared/public code**. I totally support that; if I can get an amnesty for the things they made me do against my will, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about MooTools, but there is a simple way in native JS to do this..

```
    var orgAppendChild = document.appendChild;  
    document.appendChild = localAppendHandler;


    var domElement = new Class({...});
    var MyObject = new domElement(...);
    // document.appendChild(MyObject);

     var ss = document.createElement('tr'); 
document.appendChild (ss);


    function localAppendHandler(MyObject)
    {
     if (MyObject instanceof domElement)
        UrCustomRoutine(MyObject )
        else
            orgAppendChild(MyObject);


    }

    function UrCustomRoutine(MyObject ){
    //your custom routine
    }
```

Hope this helps

**Update:**
   From your further explanation (handling appendChild of any DOM element), i understand that there is no generic way of defining local hanlders to trap  the event.

But there is a workaround (this is very ugly i know). Means you have to define a LocalHandler for the DOM element before you are goin to use the  appendChild .

Before doing this
    document.getElementByID('divTarget').appendChild()

you have to reassign the localhandler to the element you need to access

```
    orgAppendChild = document.getElementById('divTarget').appendChild;  
    document.getElementById('divTarget').appendChild = localAppendHandler;
    var sss = document.createElement('table'); 
    document.getElementById('divTarget').appendChild(sss);
```

**Another Alternative:**
If you wanted to keep it simple, i suggest this alternate way. Create AppendChild local method which accepts object and the node name as param.

```
    function AppendChild(MyObject ,Node)
    {
           if (MyObject instanceof domElement)
               //your custom routine
           else if (Node=="" && (MyObject instanceof domElement==false))
               document.appendChild(MyObject);
           else if (Node!="" && (MyObject instanceof domElement==false))
               eval( "document.getElementById('" + Node + "').appendChild(MyObject);");


    }
```

And

1. If you wanted to append DOM element to document

   ```
    AppendChild(DOMelement,"")
   ```
2. If you wanted to  append DOM element inside other
   container

   ```
    AppendChild(DOMelement,"divTarget")
   ```
3. If you wanted to process your custom object

   ```
    AppendChild(customObject,"")
   ```

this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Ramesh, it's so simple that it's brilliant.  I will check if there is any problem with mootools and this solution.

Comment: Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"  code: "3" nsresult: "0x80530003 (NS_ERROR_DOM_HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR)"  location: "http://10.0.0.11/lab/theo.aspx Line: 490"]

Comment: i dont know what it means.. i have tested here.. it works fine... i have updated script,, pls check out

Comment: OK i found the problem, maybe you can help:
with your implementation if I do:
document.appendChild() it works
if I do: document.getElementByID('divTarget').appendChild() doesn't work

Comment: I want to override *.appendChild()

Comment: What do you think if I make a list of overrides:
HTMLDivElement, etc...
Would this work?

Comment: Guys pls leave a feedback why you downvote.... the above method works as OP expected (from his initial question)... Run the code yuorself before you downvote it....

Comment: @Theofanis, i have added another approach.. check out this

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Thank you for this.
I know how to create my own function for this, I just want to override the native way.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude.. but it seems that both you and Theofanis are trying to bend over backwards to cobble a solution using `appendChild`, when the simplest answer is to use a _separate_ function, as in your `AppendChild`

Comment: The point of this question is to extend appendChild; Had that not been the point, this question would not have been posted here today.

Comment: this is not very mootools - what's the point in using the framework when you go around the methods that are already provided...

Comment: Although this isn't the answer I was looking for, it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

you ought to look at using **object.toElement()** in your class

http://blog.kassens.net/toelement-method

then just use document.body.inject(instanceObject);

Comment: why is this being downvoted - it is the correct and proper way to do it through mootools as provided by the framework. here's another example of class to element: http://bit.ly/5BOQ8s

Answer (score 0):

```
var originAppend = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild = function(el){ 
    // do something to el
    originAppend.call(this, el);
}
```